# Segmentation Fault - declare and init array in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am very new to C. coming from Python, Java and C# worlds. This might be a stupid question but I am getting segmentation fault:

```
// struct for storing matrices
typedef struct {
    int m;
    int n;   
    float* elts;
} Matrix;
```

and in my main method:

```
 Matrix A;
    A.n = 3;
    A.m = 3;
    memcpy( A.elts, (float[]) {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f, 9.0f}, 9 * sizeof(float));  // seg fault because of this memcpy.
```

I also tried without the `f`, same issue.
Can you help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `A.elts` to point to. You can do this with `malloc`. What you are doing is coping the constant array you specified into whatever address `elts` happens to point to (it is uninitialized).

You can also point `A.elts` to the constant array like so:

```
float *myFloats = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f };
A.elts = myFloats;
```

Answer (score 3):

In C arrays and pointers are related, but they are not the same. It is not enough to declare a pointer in order to make it an array: you need to set that pointer to a value pointing to a block of memory of sufficient size.

To make your example work, add

```
A.elts = malloc(sizeof(float) * 9);
```

before calling `memcpy`. Otherwise, the pointer `elts` remains uninitialized, so writing to memory pointed by that pointer is undefined behavior. Note that you would need to call `free(A.elts)` when you are done with the array.

Another alternative would be declaring `elts` as a fixed-size array, not as a pointer:

```
float elts[9];
```

This would not allow resizing the array, though.

Answer (score 2):

You have not allocated any memory to hold the float values.  Prior to the memcpy you need something like:

A.elts = malloc(9* sizeof(float));